# How to dynamically change the themes in extjs 4.2 project?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have created new project in Extjs 4.2. I would like to provide an option in the UI to dynamically change the theme. I have a created a combo box with theme names like "Classic" and "Gray". Whenever i select a particular theme. The app should convert into that theme.

Please Help.

Thanks Much

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to swtich extjs themes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121350/how-to-swtich-extjs-themes)

Comment: Have you looked at the samples that come with the SDK? They do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply get the handler in your combo box to load the css for whatever theme you select.  The new selectors in the loaded css will override the previous ones and will update the theme.

There is also a function **Ext.util.CSS.swapStyleSheet** that will perform this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Though Ext.util.CSS.swapStyleSheet will work, It has few drawbacks:

**1. It takes more time to render the page with new CSS theme.

2. While switching between themes, your page will be out of any css for a while. That will make the page look bad (broken and plain).

3. Unnecessary scrollbars will appear on the screen.**

I overcame these by using Javascript ways..

Here,

1. Include all the CSS files in your HTML file.

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" id="theme1" type="text/css" href="../Theme1.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" id="theme2" type="text/css" href="../Theme2.css" />
   ```
2. Disable all the themes except one you want as default.

   ```
   document.getElementById('theme1').disabled = true;
   document.getElementById('theme2').disabled = false;
   ```

   Now the page will be loaded with 'theme2'.
3. If you want to switch the theme. Do the vice versa of the above..

   ```
   document.getElementById('theme1').disabled = false;
   document.getElementById('theme2').disabled = true;
   ```

In this way, the switching will be real fast. Since we have loaded all the css file initially. It will not ask the server for new theme everytime.

It worked for me very well.