# Theming in extjs, working with css

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I see this is a topic that has been touched many times. But unfortunately, I did not find the answer to my specific question/problem
I am following this doc: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/theming-section-styling-your-application

My questions are

1. Is one forced to develope custom css using this the .scss format/files?
   can't one use the .css format that most people already know? This also
   makes things easier, since one can find the class and id of a component in 
   the browser, and create a custom theme while seeing the changes on the fly.
   Maybe there is a section explaining that this is possible, but I failed to
   find it
2. Since users will have different themes, I want to be able to change theme
   dynamically. In the doc, to change a theme, I have to add it in the 
   sencha.cfg file: `app.theme=my-custom-theme`
   Do I have to write code that make changes in the .cfg file to achieve this
   or is there a better way?

I already have a huge project, where I use the classic theme, and using 
extjs 4.2.3

Thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to swtich extjs themes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121350/how-to-swtich-extjs-themes)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use scss, but doing sencha themes using scss is far easier than a new css theme from scratch. Using SCSS, you can derive from an existing theme, only have to change like 100 SASS variables and click compile, and most things will look good - you don't have to write 900kb CSS styles by hand.