# How to Implement a Theme Switcher (Light/Dark Mode) in ExtJS 6.6 Classic Toolkit?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am working on an ExtJS 6.6 application using the Classic toolkit and currently have the Triton theme set as the default. I'd like to add functionality that allows users to switch between light/dark modes or between other predefined themes within the application. Despite searching through the documentation and forums, I haven't found a clear guide or example on how to achieve this in ExtJS 6.6 specifically.

It can be a toggle between two themes or a combobox like the one in sencha examples:
[ExtJS Theme Viewer](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/examples/classic/themes/)

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. I looked into dynamically loading different CSS files associated with the themes like here:
   [how to swtich extjs themes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121350/how-to-swtich-extjs-themes)
2. I considered using SASS variables to switch styles but couldn't figure out how to apply changes dynamically at runtime.

Has anyone implemented a similar feature in ExtJS <= 6.6 or can offer insights into the best approach to take? Any advice or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121350/how-to-swtich-extjs-themes/9123658#9123658

Comment: @SergeyBogdanov yes, I have linked this question in the problem description already