How to change classic app theme with page reload in ExtJS 7?
Previously in ExtJS 4, to change the theme, we used to write a condition in index.html and choose corresponding css file.
Today, with such new things as senchacmd, the build process, bootstrap.js, everything became a little more complicated.

I have 2 themes already extended from theme-triton: "dark" and "light" build in separate packages.
app.json contains default theme in root level: "theme":"light"

What should I do next to switch from theme to theme and save the selection?
Is there any solution through Ext.Package?
Or what is the best place to substitude css theme files?

Does this answer help you?

Take a look here. Seems to be a dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77982149/how-to-implement-a-theme-switcher-light-dark-mode-in-extjs-6-6-classic-toolkit
